# how to define a variable

Tags: javascript

// Check if the user is ready to play!

```
confirm("I.AM.READY!");


var age=18
```

var age = prompt("What's your age?");

```
if (age>=18)
{
console.log(You can play);

}
else
{console.log(we take no responsibilty);

}
```

Thanks a lot guys! Ive rectified the mistakes, ive completed my project (this was a small part of it) and I want others to play my game so how do i do that, tried making a .bat file but it didnt work.

Comment: You don't quote variable names. "age" becomes a literal string instead of a reference to age variable.

Comment: You should consider finishing a couple of good JavaScript tutorials first.

Comment: You should look at the line number associated with the error message and look at the code on that line.

Comment: There are minimum 10 mistakes in your code

Comment: I am learning from code academy

Comment: The error derives from the line `console.log(You can play);`. Plain text always needs to be put in quotes. In your case JavaScript thinks that "you", "can" and "play" are identifiers and the syntax doesn't support several identifiers in a row, just separated by a space. But as said before, that's not the only issue in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this :

```
confirm("I.AM.READY!");
var age=18;
age = prompt("What's your age?");
if (+age>=18)
{
  console.log("You can play");
}
else
{
  console.log("we take no responsibilty");
}
```

[console.log(param);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log) , takes the below as parameters :

> **obj1 ... objN** :
>   A list of JavaScript objects to output. The string representations of each of these objects are appended together in the order listed and output.
>
> **msg**:
>   A JavaScript string containing zero or more substitution strings.
>
> **subst1 ... substN**:
>   JavaScript objects with which to replace substitution strings within msg. This gives you additional control over the format of the output.

```
console.log(we take no responsibilty); // <<missing the quotes around the String
```

Comment: This doesn't address the error message the question is about

Comment: it does and it did, thanks a lot!

Comment: but why did you enter +age and not age

Comment: @VaibhavSharma — To cast it to a Number

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to redefine the same variable like you have done:

```
var age
var age=18
var age = prompt("What's your age?");
```

Also you should have a semicolon after a variable declaration.

For example:

```
var age = 18;
```

Will define a variable called `age` and assign it to the value 18.  If you want to change the variables value, simply do:

```
age = 20;  // No need to use var again as the variable has been declared.
```

Also when using a conditional statement, you want to compare the variables value not the string literal `age`.  Your conditional statement should read:

```
   if (age >= 18) {

   }
```

I have made a quick demo of what I believe you are trying to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/S6tu7/

Answer (score -2):

Okay, I fixed my code. This should fix it:

```
confirm("I.AM.READY!");
var age;
age=18;
age = prompt("What's your age?");
if  (age >= 18 ) {
   console.log("You can play");
}
else
{
    console.log("we take no responsibilty");
}
```

The error the OP is referring to was due to this:

```
console.log(You can play);
```

Which should have said:

```
console.log("You can play");
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't. It will fix a completely different problem that doesn't relate to the error message the question is about at all.

Comment: And.. That is only **one** of the *many* errors in the code posted in the question.